# Python: how can HTMLParser handle data from a subtag

Tags: python, html-parsing, overriding

So in a HTML document at a URL i'm interested in, the information I want on each page is not uniquely defined by the tag immediately around it, but by the tag before, that is it looks something like

```
<div class="unique">
<span class="not unique>
data I want to get
</span>
</div>
```

In my HTMLParser class I overrided the handle_starttag method with this

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    self.inLink = False
    if tag == 'div':
        for name, value in attrs:
            if name == 'class' and value == 'unique':
                self.inLink = True
                self.lasttag = tag
    if tag == 'span':
        if self.lasttag == 'div' and self.inLink:
            self.inlink = True
            self.lasttag = tag
```

but it doesn't work. Why doesn't this set my starttag to any span tag within a div tag that has class = "unique", and how is this commonly done?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question: Few people use the HTMLParser class directly at all, for a variety of reasons. Most of us use one or more of a variety of products including BeautifulSoup, selenium, scrapy, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the insight - the more I've researched it the more I'm seeing that point myself. I did actually manage to resolve this issue, and have posted an answer below.

Comment: You're welcome. And congratulations; not everyone can do that. Just imagine doing that for all the scraping done nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve this issue by doing the following:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.inLink = False
        if tag == 'div':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'class' and value == 'unique':
                    self.inLinkReady = True
        if tag == 'span':
            if self.inLinkReady:
                self.inLink = True
                self.lasttag = tag
                self.inLinkReady = False
```

:)